# Simultaneously edit two identical files in two locations with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have two servers with identical config files on both servers. When I make a change to one, I have to go over and make the change on the other server. Is there a way with Notepad++ to be able to edit both identical files in a single window? as if its just one file, just saved in two locations?

Comment: Don't know about Notepad++, but there are a 101 methods to sync files between different computers, including rsync, ftp and git. What to use depend on the OS and what kind of needs you have. Doing the syncing outside Notepad++ doesn't bind you to a specific editor.

Comment: @HAL9000, this is true, however, we do not want to use DFS because if one server server is compromised, the compromised files will DFS to the other server.  using an external sync tool would work, but then its an added step, and if Im taking an added step, I might as well copy-paste with both files open. I was just hoping I could edit both files at the same time and save a little time when troubleshooting both servers.